# MSAL: Why is setting the redirectUri to a blank page recommended?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm reading this document: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/initialization.md

It is written that:

> When using popup APIs we recommend setting the `redirectUri` to a blank page or a page that does not implement MSAL. This will help prevent potential issues as well as improve performance.

1. What are "potential issues" and "performance"?
2. If I set the `redirectUri` to a blank page, is the user redirected to the blank page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For silent and popup flows, the main window for the app (which initiated the actions) will monitor the iframe/popup for the redirect back to the application and then parse out the response. Because that main window is doing all the work, MSAL doesn't need to be running on the redirect URI used for those actions.

For `loginRedirect/acquireTokenRedirect`, the main window itself gets redirected to the login screen and then back to the app, and so the redirect page used must itself have MSAL in order to process the response.

> 1. What are "potential issues" and "performance"?

Not sure about the "potential issues" and "performance", but if we set a non-blank redirect uri here, it may cause timeout issue. See [this post](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2263#issuecomment-691191179).

> 2. If I set the redirectUri to a blank page, is the user redirected to the blank page?

No. It won't redirect the user to the blank page because main window will do all the work.

Comment: This is all correct. In regards to potential issues and performance, for silent and popup requests, the browser needs to load your redirect uri before the response can be parsed, and if this page takes a long time to load, it can impact performance of those requests. The most common issue we see is the page used for the redirect uri mangles/removes the response hash before the main MSAL instance has a chance to parse it, which can result in timeouts.

Comment: @jasonnutter What typically causes that "most common issue" you mention, and how is it solved?  I am indeed intermittently getting the error `hash_does_not_contain_known_properties` with my Angular/MSAL integration.  Incidentally, my Angular app is hosted in my Web API project (using the MS [SpaProxy facility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0)). My blank-page route handling looks like `{ path: 'blank', component: BlankComponent }`. Something to fix there?